# Print URL's from webpage to STDOUT in Perl

Tags: perl, web-scraping

How do I print URL's from an HTML page to STDOUT, and iterate over them to do the same?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;         
use LWP::Simple qw(get);
use HTML::TreeBuilder 5 -weak;

my $name = 'perl';
my $limit = 100;
my $offset = 0;

    
my $total;
while (1) {
my $url = "http://hoshikuso.jp/?to=hunminj@ktng.com?limit=$limit&offset=$offset";
my $html = get $url;
my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new;
print ($tree);
$tree->parse($html);

if (not $total) {
    $total = $tree->look_down('http', 'https')->as_text;
    say $total;
}
};
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: You're interpolating a variable called `@ktng` into your `$url`, and you have an endless loop.

Comment: To fix the problem @simbabque identified, put a \ before the @ in your $url definition.

Comment: I escaped the @ after the qs, below is error seen:

vivek.singh@20E-X522LVDQ-33R ~ % perl Desktop/scrap.pl 
Can't call method "as_text" on an undefined value at Desktop/scrap.pl line 21.
HTML::TreeBuilder=HASH(0x7f9d3a06a900)%

Comment: Update your question with your changes and new information.

Answer (score 2):

You can do most of this right in a [Mojo::Collections](https://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojo/Collection) pipelines. There's even a `size` method that will tell you how many items are in the collection without you counting yourself:. A `grep` removes the weird `a` tags in that page, the `map` can do what you like, and after that, `size` gets you the total. I have lots of examples in [Mojo Web Clients](https://leanpub.com/mojo_web_clients):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use v5.10;
use open qw(:std :utf8);

use warnings;
use strict;
use Mojo::UserAgent;
use Mojo::Util qw(trim);

my $url = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurants-g147275-Varadero_Matanzas_Province_Cuba.html';
my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;


my $count = $ua->get( $url )
    ->res
    ->dom
    ->find( 'a[href]' )
    ->grep( sub { $_->attr('href') =~ m|\A/RestaurantsNear-| } )
    ->map( sub {
        my $t = trim( $_->all_text );
        printf qq(%s -> "%s"\n), $_->attr("href"), $t;
        })
    ->size;

say "Total is $count";
```

Comment: Thanks Brian, I like to come to SO to improve and this certainly hits the spot. FYI, your "Mojo Web Clients" link does not work.

Answer (score 1):

This code should get you well on your way to your goal.  These three doc pages should be all you need to get further on your way [Mojo::DOM](https://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojo/DOM) [Mojo::Collection](https://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojo/Collection) [Mojo::UserAgent](https://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojo/UserAgent)

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Mojo::UserAgent;

my $url = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurants-g147275-Varadero_Matanzas_Province_Cuba.html';
my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;

my $total=0;

my $page = $ua->get( $url )->res->dom() ;   ## returns Mojo::DOM object of whole page
for my $node ( $page->find( "a[href]" )->each() )  ## returns Mojo::DOM object of a tags with href attribute
{
    print "###########\n";
    print $node->text() . "\n";
    print $node->attr("href")  ."\n";
    $total++;
}

print "\n\ntotal A tags with href attribute : $total\n";
```